# Fatal Error: Declaration of CakeDC\OracleDriver\Database\OCI8\OCI8Connection::query must be compatible with PDO::query ( Cake Php 4.4.14 )

Tags: php, windows, oracle, cakephp

I am created a project on cake php and try to connect with an oracle instance provided from my office to work on that oracle database. I installed CakePHP 4 Driver which is get from [Github CakePHP 4 Driver](https://github.com/CakeDC/cakephp-oracle-driver)  and followed the instruction had been written there. After doing all the steps, when i run my project i came up with this error

> Fatal error: Declaration of CakeDC\OracleDriver\Database\OCI8\OCI8Connection::query($statement, $mode = PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, $arg3 = null) must be compatible with PDO::query(string $query, ?int $fetchMode = null, mixed ...$fetchModeArgs): PDOStatement|false in E:\my-cake-project\vendor\cakedc\cakephp-oracle-driver\src\Database\OCI8\OCI8Connection.php on line 130

I Enabled all the necessary extension (php.ini) and oracle driver in my project did according to the documentation provided on the github repo that i used.
my **php.ini** file looks like this: (enabled extension )

```
extension=curl
;extension=ffi
;extension=ftp
extension=fileinfo
;extension=gd
extension=gettext
;extension=gmp
extension=intl
;extension=imap
extension=mbstring
extension=exif      ; Must be after mbstring as it depends on it
extension=mysqli
;extension=oci8_12c  ; Use with Oracle Database 12c Instant Client
extension=oci8_19  ; Use with Oracle Database 19 Instant Client
;extension=odbc
;extension=openssl
;extension=pdo_firebird
extension=pdo_mysql
extension=pdo_oci
;extension=pdo_odbc
;extension=pdo_pgsql
extension=pdo_sqlite
;extension=pgsql
;extension=shmop

; The MIBS data available in the PHP distribution must be installed.
; See https://www.php.net/manual/en/snmp.installation.php
;extension=snmp

;extension=soap
;extension=sockets
;extension=sodium
extension=sqlite3
;extension=tidy
;extension=xsl
extension=zip
```

**Application.php:**

```
public function bootstrap(): void
    {
        // Call parent to load bootstrap from files.
        parent::bootstrap();

        if (PHP_SAPI === 'cli') {
            $this->bootstrapCli();
        } else {
            FactoryLocator::add(
                'Table',
                (new TableLocator())->allowFallbackClass(false)
            );
        }

        /*
         * Only try to load DebugKit in development mode
         * Debug Kit should not be installed on a production system
         */
        if (Configure::read('debug')) {
            $this->addPlugin('DebugKit');
        }

        // Added oracle driver plugin
        $this->addPlugin(\CakeDC\OracleDriver\Plugin::class, ['bootstrap' => true]);
    }

 protected function bootstrapCli(): void
    {
        $this->addOptionalPlugin('Cake/Repl');
        $this->addOptionalPlugin('Bake');

        $this->addPlugin('Migrations');

        // Added oracle driver plugin
        $this->addPlugin(\CakeDC\OracleDriver\Plugin::class, ['bootstrap' => true]);
    }
```

**./config/app.php:**

```
'Datasources' => [
        /*
         * These configurations should contain permanent settings used
         * by all environments.
         *
         * The values in app_local.php will override any values set here
         * and should be used for local and per-environment configurations.
         *
         * Environment variable based configurations can be loaded here or
         * in app_local.php depending on the applications needs.
         */

        'default' => [
            'className' => 'CakeDC\OracleDriver\Database\OracleConnection',
            'driver' => 'CakeDC\OracleDriver\Database\Driver\OracleOCI', # For OCI8
            // 'driver' => 'CakeDC\\OracleDriver\\Database\\Driver\\OraclePDO', # For PDO_OCI
            'persistent' => true,           // Database persistent connection between http requests
            'host' => 'oracle.xyz.com',          // Database host name or IP address
            'port' => 1111,                    // Database port number (default: 1521)
            'username' => 'myoracle',         // Database username
            'password' => 'xxxxxxxxxx',       // Database password
            'database' => 'myoracle_db',     // Database name (maps to Oracle's `SERVICE_NAME`)
            'sid' => 'ORCL',                 // Database System ID (maps to Oracle's `SID`)
            'instance' => '',               // Database instance name (maps to Oracle's `INSTANCE_NAME`)
            'pooled' => '',                 // Database pooling (maps to Oracle's `SERVER=POOLED`)
            'flags' => [],                  // Database low level parameters for OCI or PDO connection. Auto-generated by default
            'encoding' => '',               // Database charset (default same as database charset)
            'init' => [],                   // Array of queries executed at connection
            'cacheMetadata' => true,        // Enable cakephp schema caching
            'server_version' => 19,        // Oracle server numeric version ex.: 11,12,19
            'autoincrement' => true,        // Enable autoincrement insteadof custom triggers in case of oracle 12+
        ],
```

As a newbie in cake-php, I am not sure what am i doing wrong? Mysql working perfectly on the other hand. A little help will be very helpful for me.

**My Environment:**

```
> PHP 8.2.7
> CakePHP 4.4.14 Strawberry
> Oracle Database 19.3
> Oracle Client 19.19
> Windows Platform
```

I Want to connect my oracle database smoothly as I connect Mysql on cakePHP project

Comment: Your driver link just goes to the Stack Overflow main page. Where did you get it from?

Comment: My mistake I got it from here: https://github.com/CakeDC/cakephp-oracle-driver

Comment: According to that site, you need version 5 of that plugin to work with Cake 4. Is that the version you have? The error reported looks like a pretty significant mismatch between function prototypes, which seems likely indicative of a major version mismatch, not a minor one.

Comment: @GregSchmidt My version is 5.0.0. But still having problems

Comment: Maybe send a support question to CakeDC through their site.